# SharePoint Installation Error : Application Server Role ,Web Server Roll Configuration Error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, administration, central-administration, farm-admin

I am installing SharePoint 2013 in my windows server 2008 r2 , And Coming across to the below issue .Can any one help me what is the issue and how can I solve this.

[image]

Comment: What does the log file say regarding that specific IIS Role error?

Comment: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i -enable Run this command and try to run prerequisite again and also please check the logs. if possible  update  the question with the error logs

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options here:

1. Enable .Net 3.5 on the server and retry the pre-requisite installation.
2. Manually add the required features using PowerShell.

Note that the installation is attempting to add the .Net 3.5 feature to the machine during the pre-requisite installation, and failing, so it's worth adding it anyway. The installation of this feature normally requires that the server either has access to the installation media, or has access to the internet to allow it to download the required files and appropriate policies in place to enable it to go to the internet for the files to install .Net 3.5.

The PowerShell to add the required features is:

> Import-Module Servermanager
>
> Add-WindowsFeature
>   NET-HTTP-Activation,NET-Non-HTTP-Activ,NET-WCF-Pipe-Activation45,NET-WCF-HTTP-Activation45,Web-Server,Web-WebServer,Web-Common-Http,Web-Static-Content,Web-Default-Doc,Web-Dir-Browsing,Web-Http-Errors,Web-App-Dev,Web-Asp-Net,Web-Asp-Net45,Web-Net-Ext,Web-Net-Ext45,Web-ISAPI-Ext,Web-ISAPI-Filter,Web-Health,Web-Http-Logging,Web-Log-Libraries,Web-Request-Monitor,Web-Http-Tracing,Web-Security,Web-Basic-Auth,Web-Windows-Auth,Web-Filtering,Web-Digest-Auth,Web-Performance,Web-Stat-Compression,Web-Dyn-Compression,Web-Mgmt-Tools,Web-Mgmt-Console,Web-Mgmt-Compat,Web-Metabase,WAS,WAS-Process-Model,WAS-NET-Environment,WAS-Config-APIs,Web-Lgcy-Scripting,Windows-Identity-Foundation,Xps-Viewer -verbose

The PowerShell above adds all of the features that the pre-requisite installer adds. The installation of the required software (e.g. SQL Server 2008 SP1 Native Client) is additional to the above.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple solution after digging out the whole internet, Go to c:\Windows\system32 and rename the file from servermanager.exe to servermanagercmd.exe.....it will resolve the issue